# What is $-\infty \cdot - \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

What is $-\infty \cdot - \infty$?

And what do I do if I come across it in an assignment when taking the limit?

E.g.
$$\lim_{x \to - \infty} (x \cdot x) $$

Since $x^{2}$ is continuous, can you just set in for $x$ and get:

$$\lim_{x \to - \infty} (x^{2}) = \infty$$

Comment: The limit is correct. $x^2$ is non-negative and for $x\rightarrow -\infty$ becomes bigger and bigger. Hence, the limit is $\infty$

Comment: The answer is correct but it does not result from continuity of $x^{2}$ on the real line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x$,

$$x\cdot x=(-x)(-x)$$ so anything you can conclude for $\infty$ is also valid for $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Though this has been answered in the comment, I am writing a proof for this so as to

1. clear this question from the unanswered queue, and
2. provide a *direct* argument from the basics, independent of the product rule for continuous function because to [Prove that the product of two continuous functions is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1593789/290189), you need the limit values $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ to be *finite* and $a \in \Bbb{R}$ as $x \to a$ so that $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ are properly *defined*.

Let $M > 1$ be an arbitrarily large number.  For all $x < -M$, $x^2 > M^2 > M$, so that $x^2 \to \infty$ as $x \to -\infty$.